# Describing motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

How can we describe motion of a particle moving with velocity $v$ along positive $x$-axis acted upon by a force for an instant at angle $a$ down of positive $x$-axis in x-y plane?

I tried by writing equations of motion along $x$-axis and $y$-axis for the particle but couldn't figure out how to find the change in state of motion of particle in an instant?

can you help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by instant? Do you mean an interval $\delta t$, arbitrarly small but still greater than zero? Second, is the particle constrained on the x-axis?

Comment: no particle is allowed to move anywhere and yes i mean by the term instant the same as you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the system you are describing from a very rigorous perspective: we have a dimensionless particle of mass $m$ moving along the real line with velocity $\dot x(t)$. All of a sudden, a force $\vec F(t)$ acts on the particle for an interval $\delta t$, creating an angle $\alpha$ with the real line.

For pure mathematical convenience, we describe the force as an impulse function like this

$$ F(t) = \begin{cases} F_0\cos{\alpha} \text{ if }t\in \delta t \\
0 \text{ otherwise}  
\end{cases}$$

According to Newton's Law: $F(t)=m {\ddot x(t)}$ so we just need to integrate.

$$\dot x(t) = \frac{1}{m}\int_{\delta t} F(t)dt = \frac{1}{m}F_0\cos{\alpha}\delta t+v_0$$

Note that immediately after $\delta t$ the force goes back to zero, meeaning the particle will proceded with constant velocity.

Comment: what about perpendicular component of force will it not change direction of motion

Comment: Didn't you say "the particle is not allowed to move anywhere"? I assumed you meant the particle can NOT move along the $y$-axis. If that's the case, we just don't care about the perpendicular component